# React.StrictMode seems to work differently in different React version (18.1.0 vs 17.0.1)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, react-state

Let me tell you in brief what I am trying to do. As I am learning React, so following a tutorial and making a `Contact Manager`, where it will take input of name and email address for now and will save it in local storage. When I will reload the page, it will retrieve data from local storage and display it. As I am in a learning phase, I am just exploring how the state works and how I can save data in local storage, Later I will save these data to a DB.

React version I am using is:

```
 react: "18.1.0"
 react-dom: "18.1.0"
```

and my node version is:

```
17.1.0
```

I am setting the form input data to local storage by doing this:

```
   useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(contacts));
  }, [contacts]);
```

and retriving these data from local storage with the below code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const retriveContacts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY));
    if (retriveContacts) {
      setContacts(retriveContacts);
    }
  }, []);
```

I can see data is being stored in local storage from the Chrome Dev tool but whenever I am reloading the page, my goal is to retrieve the data from local storage and show the list. But after reloading, these data are not any longer visible on the page. I tried to debug, then I noticed, that when I am reloading the page, it's hitting the `app.js` component twice, the first time it's getting the data, but the second time the data is being lost.

I got a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48846289/why-is-my-react-component-is-rendering-twice), where it's saying to remove the `React.StrictMode` from `index.js` and after doing so it's working fine.

Then I tried to replace the current `index.js` with the previous react version (17.0.1) `index.js`. This is the code I tried:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./components/App";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

With this code, even with `React.StrictMode` this seems to work fine, I mean my data does not clear from local storage after reloading.

**My question is, what's the reason behind it?** Am I missing something or there is some logic behind it? The solution link I have provided is 4 years ago, and React 18 was released some time ago, can't figure out what actually I am doing wrong!

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

Below are the components to regenerate the scenario.

`Current index.js (version 18.1.0)`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./components/App";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

`App.jsx`

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "../style/App.css";
import Header from "./Header";
import AddContact from "./AddContact";
import ContactList from "./ContactList";

function App() {
  const LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = "contacts";
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);

  const addContactHandler = (contact) => {
    console.log(contact);
    setContacts([...contacts, contact]);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const retriveContacts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY));
    if (retriveContacts) {
      setContacts(retriveContacts);
      console.log(retriveContacts);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(contacts));
  }, [contacts]);

  return (
    <div className="ui container">
      <Header />
      <AddContact addContactHandler={addContactHandler} />
      <ContactList contacts={contacts} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`Header.jsx`

```js
import React from 'react';

const Header = () => {
    return(
        <div className='ui fixed menu'>
            <div className='ui center container'>
                <h2>
                    Contact Manager
                </h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Header;
```

`ContactList.jsx`

```js
import React from "react";
import ContactCard from "./ContactCard";

const ContactList = (props) => {
  const listOfContact = props.contacts.map((contact) => {
    return <ContactCard contact={contact}></ContactCard>;
  });

  return <div className="ui celled list">{listOfContact}</div>;
};

export default ContactList;
```

`AddContact.jsx`

```js
import React from "react";

class AddContact extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: "",
    email: "",
  };

  add = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.name === "" || this.state.email === "") {
      alert("ALl the fields are mandatory!");
      return;
    }
    this.props.addContactHandler(this.state);
    this.setState({ name: "", email: "" });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ui main">
        <h2>Add Contact</h2>
        <form className="ui form" onSubmit={this.add}>
          <div className="field">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="name"
              placeholder="Name"
              value={this.state.name}
              onChange={(e) => this.setState({ name: e.target.value })}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="field">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="email"
              placeholder="Email"
              value={this.state.email}
              onChange={(e) => this.setState({ email: e.target.value })}
            />
          </div>
          <button className="ui button blue">Add</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AddContact;
```

`ContactCard.jsx`

```js
import React from "react";
import user from '../images/user.png'

const ContactCard = (props) => {
    const {id, name, email} = props.contact;
    return(
        <div className="item">
        <img className="ui avatar image" src={user} alt="user" />
        <div className="content">
            <div className="header">{name}</div>
            <div>{email}</div>
        </div>
        <i className="trash alternate outline icon"
            style={{color:"red"}}></i>
    </div>
    );
};

export default ContactCard;
```

`App.css`

```css
.main {
  margin-top: 5em;
}

.center {
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.ui.search input {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}

.item {
  padding: 15px 0px !important;
}

i.icon {
  float: right;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your current setup with 2 `useEffect` in a single rendering, I guess one of the possible problems is [automatic batching in React v18](https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18.html#new-feature-automatic-batching) that causes all state updates and side-effects in one rendering.

As for your question about what's different between `React.StrictMode` in React v17 and React v18, you can find [this useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72112028/does-strict-mode-work-differently-with-react-18/72112129#72112129) with a very detailed explanation.

---

For further explanation of a possible fix in your case

```
useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(contacts));
}, [contacts]);
```

Your expectation for the above `useEffect` is *"You want it to be called when `contacts` state gets updated"*

But in fact, it has been called for the first load without `contacts` update too (when `contacts` is empty).

For the simulation, you can check the below code with some explanations *(I'm using `react: 17.0.1`, but no differences if I use `react 18.1.0`)*

```js
const App = () => {
   const [contacts, setContacts] = React.useState()
   
   React.useEffect(() => {
      console.log('initial useEffect')
      //simulate to set contacts from local storage
      //it should have data, but after this, it's overriden by the 2nd useEffect
      setContacts([{name: "testing"}])
   }, [])
   
   React.useEffect(() => {
      console.log('useEffect with dependency', { contacts })
      //you're expecting this should not be called initially
      //but it's called and updated your `contacts` back to no data
      //means it's completely wiped out all your local storage data unexpectedly
      setContacts(contacts) 
   }, [contacts])
   
   //trace contact values
   //it should have values `{name: "testing"}` after `useEffect`, but now it's rendering with nothing
   console.log({ contacts })
   
   return <div></div>
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
     <App/>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

A potential fix for it should be to add a condition to check `contacts` state availability within that `useEffect` before any updates - That would help to avoid updating local storage again with empty `contacts` unexpectedly.

```js
const App = () => {
  const [contacts, setContacts] = React.useState()

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('initial useEffect')
    //simulate to set contacts from local storage
    //it should have data, but after this, it's overriden by the 2nd useEffect
    setContacts([{
      name: "testing"
    }])
  }, [])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (contacts) {
      //now you're able to set contacts from this!
      console.log('useEffect with dependency', {
        contacts
      })
      setContacts(contacts)
    }
  }, [contacts])

  console.log({
    contacts
  }) //trace contact values

  return <div></div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<React.StrictMode>
     <App/>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, I can understand what you're saying and I will implement that. But the surprising fact for me is, suppose, suppose, If I don't make any change in any of my components, just replace index.js with version 17 index.js, then it works exactly like how I want!

Comment: Hmm interesting, the only thing I can see is React.Strictmode makes double renderings (as the answer youbshared). By the way, let me try to run the code locally

Comment: Sure, if you want I can give you the full code

Comment: Could you put it somewhere that I can fork your code from it? By the way, did you try to modify the part I mentioned in the answer? That potentially fixes your problem. @TBA

Comment: I have made the changes as you suggested and working fine. 
You can clone from [here](https://github.com/TahirAnny/Contact-Manager). I would request you to run the project with the current `index.js` file, then you will find I have commented out the previous version `index.js` code, uncomment that and run the project, I hope you will be able to regenerate the issue.

Comment: Before I start checking, I think [automatic batching in React v18](https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18.html#new-feature-automatic-batching) is another possible cause for your case. It groups all state effects to a single rendering which is not ideal for your setup with 2 `useEffect` for `setContacts` @TBA

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72112129/9201587) is good for your case @TBA

Comment: Yu, Thank you so much, your last two comments were really helpful, you better update your answer with these references, I will mark your answer as Accepted.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, @TBA! I updated the answer for the references :D