# Why my Firebase get() function fires twice inside React component?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

In the initialize file, I code like this.

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getDatabase, ref, child, get  } from "firebase/database";

const config = {

};

const app = initializeApp(config);
const db = getDatabase(app);
const dbRef = (ref(db));

get(child(dbRef, "shop_data")).then((snap) => {
    console.log(snap.val())
})
export {dbRef};
```

From here, I receive one result from console.log
[image: firebase init]

Now, in my Store component, I only put the get() function in

```
import '../css/StoreSelectable.css';
import { dbRef } from '../js/firebase_init';
import { getDatabase, ref, child, get  } from "firebase/database";

function StoreSelectable(){    
    const getStore = () => {
        get(child(dbRef, "shop_data")).then((snap) => {
            console.log(snap.val())
        })
        return;
    }
   

    return(
        <div className="Store-Selectable">
            <table id="place_option" align="center" style={{tableLayout: 'fixed'}} className="radioButtons collapseBorder">  
                <tbody>
                    
                        {getStore()}
                    
                </tbody>         
            </table>
            
        </div>
        
    );

}

export default StoreSelectable;
```

Now, firebase function fires twice.
[image]

---

Edit 10/6/2022
I tried useEffect, but it still gets the data twice. I really do not want to use Firestore since I have to rewrite a lot of codes. What should I do in this situation?

```
import "../css/StoreSelectable.css";
import { dbRef } from "../js/firebase_init";
import { getDatabase, ref, child, get } from "firebase/database";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function StoreSelectable() {
  const pin = {
    TestiKirppis: ["Jarii1", "spr1234", "6899bc73da4ace09"],
    Vaasa: ["D0ED5D57F47580F2", "spr9876", "Vas183"],
    Seinäjoki: ["a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1", "spr9999", "Seina19"],
    Kokkola: ["regT863", "spr0000", "b4b8bb4ceeaa2aee"],
  };

  const [count, setCount] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getStore = () => {
        get(child(dbRef, "shop_data")).then((snap) => {
            let val = snap.val();
            Object.keys(val).forEach((key) => {
                setCount((count) => [...count, val[key].name]);
            })
        });
    }    
    getStore();

    
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="Store-Selectable">
      <table
        id="place_option"
        align="center"
        style={{ tableLayout: "fixed" }}
        className="radioButtons collapseBorder"
      >
        <tbody>{count.map((data) => {return (<p>{data}</p>)})}</tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default StoreSelectable;
```

Comment: This may be because of Strict Mode in react

Comment: Strict twice renders a component, please check inside your index.js file if you are using <React.StrictMode> .

Comment: You're doing your fetching in the body of your component, so it's going to happen every time this component renders. You're lucky that it's only happening twice. You need to do this fetching either in a use effect, or something like an onClick, not in the body.

Comment: I need to fetch it when the page is loaded, but when I try it with useState and useEffect, it triggers 4 times instead of 2, with 2 additional times when the variable is created. https://imgur.com/a/MODRfS9

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because of strict mode in react 18. If you remove it, the issue will be resolved.

Please check : [multiple execution of files leading to multiple server calls in react js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72563616/multiple-execution-of-files-leading-to-multiple-server-calls-in-react-js)

Comment: A mode detailed explanation of strict mode is provided in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72112028/does-strict-mode-work-differently-with-react-18

Comment: I really want to keep it on to track bugs, but even useEffect triggers twice so for the moment, I am turning it off.