# too many renders using useContext and createContext

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

facing a multiple rendering issue when using useContext, here are code examples and prints showing the multiple log on each click
I'm new to using context and I'm trying to understand the concepts and whys of multi-rendering, one possibility would be to use useEffect to create something like 'didMount' or something like that, but I don't know where to put this code

Editor Page..

```js
// react
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
// components
import Header from '../../components/header/Header';
import EditHands from './components/edit-hands/EditHands';
// context
import { EditorProvider } from '../../contexts/EditorContext';

const Editor = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <EditorProvider>
        <p>Editor</p>
        <EditHands />
      </EditorProvider>
    </>
  );
};

export default Editor;
```

Editor Context

```js
import { createContext, useState } from 'react';

export const editorContext = createContext();

export const EditorProvider = ({ children }) => {
  //
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  const increaseCounter = () => setCounter(counter + 1);

  return (
    <editorContext.Provider value={{ counter, increaseCounter }}>
      {children}
    </editorContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Edit Hands => Components using context and mult rendering

```js
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
// database
import { hands } from '../../../../database/db';
// context
import { editorContext } from '../../../../contexts/EditorContext';

const EditHands = () => {
  const { counter, increaseCounter } = useContext(editorContext);

  console.log('Edit Hands counter value: ', counter);

  return (
    <>
      <button>{counter}</button>
      <button onClick={increaseCounter}>Increase</button>
      <div className='hands-containner'>
        {hands.map((hand, i) => (
          <span key={i}>{hand}</span>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
export default EditHands;
```

SS from console.log inside EditHands

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems [`Strict Mode`](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects) of React is invoking the function component twice, **so your code is fine as it is.**

`Strict Mode` is only active in development mode for safe code writing. So when you run it in production mode or turn off the `Strict Mode`, the problem would be gone.

In React 17, `console.log` is silenced by the React. But Since version 18, React does not suppress any logs. Check the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects) about this, and other [StackOverflow Question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72112028/does-strict-mode-work-differently-with-react-18)

Comment: I was thinking this, but I think React hides `console.log` calls in the second run. Did they change that?

Comment: @Halcyon React is not hiding that since version 18 as far as I know.

Comment: I see, I found this: https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/96 "We are no longer silencing console methods during the double render in Strict Mode."

Comment: ok considering that my application is small and won't have performance problems, i'll just use this to check if the mouse was clicked or not on certain components, i'll leave it as is, it's still confusing for me, but thanks for the answer